# The meaning of ratio of two sets

Tags: set-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I come accros that
$(2n-1)!!$ is  the number of permutations of 2n whose cycle type consists of n parts equal to 2; these are the involutions without fixed points (A).

Also, for each $n \in N$, let $f(n)$ is  the number of subsets of set $[n]=\ {1,2,...,n}$. Then $f(n)=2^n$ (B)

I wonder about the understanding of the "physical" meaning of the ration: A/B?
What could be the meaning of $\frac {(2n-1)!!} {2^n}$ in terms of  sets?

Also, I noticed that the ratio is very closed to $\Gamma(n+1/2)$. This is why I am trying to understand the ratio.

Finally, the ratio is very closed to recurrence: $a_{n+1}=a_n(n-1/2)$

Comment: The Gamma function identity and the recurrence are equivalent by the basic functional equation of Gamma.  You get the recurrence by viewing $(2n-1)!!$ as a product.  Try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, yes, I know that and got it with no difficulties. but the question is about the meaning in terms of sets.